# change margin-left with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want a dynamical margin-left on a given div.

I tried this code :

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var pageWidth = window.innerWidth; 
    var size = (pageWidth - 200 ) / 2;
    $('#search').css('margin-Left', size));
    alert(size);
 };
```

which doesn't work (the alert is here just for test purpose), the problem is coming from the ligne `$('#search').css('margin-Left', size));` but I can't find out where...

I've tried with a lowercase `l` on margin-left and didn't work.

Comment: $('#search').css('margin-left', size)); case sensitive

Comment: @harsha  already tried, didn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure the div has an id of 'search' and not a class?

Comment: If you inspect the div with the developer tools for your browser is there an inline style there?

Comment: @Samoth : Take a look at my answer. Will work

Comment: You should note that you have an extra closing parenthesis on your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would the following work for you?

```
document.getElementById("search").style.marginLeft = size + "px";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the type of unit you want to use.

```
$('#search').css('margin-left', size + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using marginLeft, without the hypen.

jQuery.css() documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I think there is no difference between marginLeft and margin-left!

Comment: From your own link: _jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css( "background-color" ) and .css( "backgroundColor" )._

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    alert('test');
    var pageWidth = parseInt($(window).innerWidth());
    alert(pageWidth);
    var size = (pageWidth - 200 ) / 2;
    $('#search').css('margin-left', size);
    alert(size);
})
```

HTML

```
<div id = 'search'></div>
```

CSS

```
#search
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

[**FIDDLE LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/BCdES/)